# Create a Google Chart in javascript with JSON data

Tags: javascript, pygooglechart

I need a column chart data with JSON, in order to automate this chart,  but i dont no how do this.

So this is my JS Code:

```
function drawChart() {

    const container = document.querySelector('#chart');

    let chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

    //Informações data.json

    let dataRequest = new Request("./datas/data.json");

    fetch(dataRequest)
        .then(function(resp) {
            return resp.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    // Informações gráficos

    let data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Volume", "Valor"],
        ["DA", 67],
        ["CIF", 23],
        ["Expurgo", 45]
    ]);

    const options = {
        titlePosition: 'none',
        colors: ['#ed4a0e', '#15466e'],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        animation: {
            startup: true,
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'out',
        },
        hAxis: { textStyle: { color: 'white' }, titleTextStyle: { color: 'white', fontSize: 15 } },
        vAxis: { textStyle: { color: 'white' }, titleTextStyle: { color: 'white', fontSize: 15 } },
        chartArea: { width: 250, height: 200 },
        legend: {
            textStyle: { color: '#ffffff', fontSize: 13 }
        }
    };



    chart.draw(data, options)
};
```

My json:

```
[
    ["Volume", "Valor"],
    ["DA", 67],
    ["CIF", 23],
    ["Expurgo", 45]
]
```

I never do this before, and need a little help,if someone help whit this 
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: What's your problem here ?

Comment: I try to populating my Column Chart with data dynamically from JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "false" as last parameter

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Volume", "Valor"],
    ["DA", 67],
    ["CIF", 23],
    ["Expurgo", 45]
],
false); // 'false' means that the first row contains labels, not data.
```

Comment: but how I use JSON data inside the chart?

Comment: Is "data" your current JSON object, formatted as shown ?